# How to upload and process all specified Shiny inputs simultaneously when accessing previously downloaded inputs?

Tags: r, shiny

The simplified code below allows the user to download ("Save") user inputs and retrieve them later using an Upload action button. The image below shows how this App works. The problem is that there are two input variables that interact: `time_window` from the `sliderInput()` and the user's inputs into the 2-column input matrix called `matInput()`. If the user has saved the inputs, and in another session for example has the `time_window` set at 5, and tries retrieving the saved scenario where `time_window` had been set at 10, it takes 2 clicks of the Upload action button to retrieve that saved scenario: the first click retrieves the `sliderInput()` value of 10 from the saved scenario and the second click retrieves the values in the `matInput()` objects that was saved. You can see in the code where in the `downloadHander()` I group the two inputs as `saveRDS(list(var_1_input = input$var_1_input, time_window = input$time_window)` and in the `observe()` for upload I group these inputs together as `updateSliderInput(session, "time_window", value = uploaded_values$time_window) updateMatrixInput(session, "var_1_input", value = uploaded_values$var_1_input)`; but this doesn't work to simultaneously retrieve and process the inputs.

So, when uploading saved inputs, how can they be accessed and processed simultaneously with one single click of an action button?

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

matInput <- function(name, x) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(c(x, 0), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 0, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

matStretch <- function(mat, time_window, col_name) {
  mat[, 1] <- pmin(mat[, 1], time_window)
  df <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = time_window, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, col_name)))
  df[, col_name] <- ifelse(seq_along(df[, 1]) %in% mat[, 1], mat[match(seq_along(df[, 1]), mat[, 1]), 2], 0)
  return(df)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('modal_upload', 'Upload'),
  downloadButton("save_btn", "Save"),
  sliderInput("time_window","Time window (W):", min = 1, max = 10, value = 10),
  uiOutput("Vectors"),
  tableOutput("table2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  time_window <- reactive(input$time_window)
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({matInput("var_1_input", input$time_window)})
  
  output$save_btn <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() paste0("scenario", ".rds"),
    content = function(file) saveRDS(list(var_1_input = input$var_1_input, time_window = input$time_window), file)
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$modal_upload, {
    showModal(modalDialog(fileInput("upload_file_input", "Upload:", accept = c('.rds'))))
  })
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$upload_file_input)) {
      uploaded_values <- readRDS(input$upload_file_input$datapath)
      updateSliderInput(session, "time_window", value = uploaded_values$time_window)
      updateMatrixInput(session, "var_1_input", value = uploaded_values$var_1_input)
      removeModal()
    }
  })
  
  var_1 <- reactive(input$var_1_input)
  output$table2 <- renderTable(matStretch(var_1(), time_window(), "Var_1"))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The updates are being applied simultaneously (which can be verified as the modal is being closed), but they are subsequently being overwritten when they trigger reactive events in `output$vector` and `output$table2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more direct approach for the server code to ensure the `output$` variables are not overwritten by subsequent reactives:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({matInput("var_1_input", input$time_window)})
  
  output$save_btn <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() paste0("scenario", ".rds"),
    content = function(file) saveRDS(list(var_1_input = input$var_1_input, time_window = input$time_window), file)
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$modal_upload, {
    showModal(modalDialog(fileInput("upload_file_input", "Upload:", accept = c('.rds'))))
  })
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$upload_file_input)) {
      uploaded_values <- readRDS(input$upload_file_input$datapath)
      updateSliderInput(session, "time_window", value = uploaded_values$time_window)
      updateMatrixInput(session, "var_1_input", value = uploaded_values$var_1_input)
      output$Vectors <- renderUI({matInput("var_1_input", uploaded_values$time_window)})
      output$table2 <- renderTable(matStretch(uploaded_values$var_1_input, uploaded_values$time_window, "Var_1"))
      removeModal()
    }
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderTable(matStretch(input$var_1_input, input$time_window, "Var_1"))
}
```

Comment: I see, so the trick is to include `output$Vectors <- renderUI(...)` and `output$table2 <- renderTable(...)` in the `observe(...)` function referencing the uploaded values.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved with using invalidateLater, to not try to update the matrix, until the time window is adjusted to be as the upload required.

```
 observe({
    if (!is.null(input$upload_file_input)) {
      uploaded_values <- readRDS(input$upload_file_input$datapath)
      
      updateSliderInput(session, "time_window", value = uploaded_values$time_window)
      if(shiny::isolate(input$time_window)==uploaded_values$time_window){
        print("fine")
        updateMatrixInput(session, "var_1_input", 
                          value = uploaded_values$var_1_input)
      } else {
        print("problem so wait; then try again")
        invalidateLater(300)
      }
      removeModal()
    }
  })
```